# Create an email redirect with mailgun when namecheap is your domain provider

Tags: email, dns, mailgun, namecheap

I am using mailgun as my mail provider for my domain. My domain is hosted through namecheap. I want to set up an email redirect like `admin@mydomain.com` to go to my personal email address. I can not do this through namecheap because I have a mail provider set up. Here is what I see in the main domain configuration page on namecheap:

[image]

I set up a matching route in mailgun however, this only works for the mailgun subdomain. So I can create a redirect for `admin@mg.mydomain.com` which works, but not `admin@mydomain.com`. No errors or bounces for `admin@mydomain.com` it just doesn't work.

Any ideas how to make this work? I have a ticket pending with mailgun, so I will report the solution here for others once its resolved.

Comment: "so I will report the solution here"  Please don't. Your question is not related to programming and hence is offtopic here, besides using very bad obfuscation. [su] is probably more suited, or maybe [sf] or [webmasters.se] please read their respective help section to find what is ontopic there.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this with the settings below. The Host Records were:

[image]

...and the MX records are:

[image]

Then in Mailgun > Receiving, I created a route that looks like this:

[image]